# Echarts - grouping bars and diplay only macro in legend and tooltip

Tags: echarts

[image]

In this scenario I'd like to create a bar chart: x axys is first columns "month", values in cols "carts" and "orders" have to be overlayed (orders will never exceed the number of carts).

Also, legend should show only macros (Direct, ADV, etc.) and show/hide both values "carts" and "orders", and tooltip have to show all data in that month.

I tried searching in documentation, but I didn't find anything like that.

[image]

This is an example of what I mean: Every macro (es. Direct, ADV) have to be series, and each serie have to contain stacked values for orders and carts, differentiated by color or transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want but [heres](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygiBTWBeGBtAUDGAb3wJigEsBbVALhgHIAGARgFoAmR9gZnoBoSBOOQBOqYFADCdZowGl4o8VADyMuYMViJAEXIAzfXQ0KEcAG7SYs-aTPm1MAOy2C9vYbrcSAX1vEFCmo6JnYOLl5XLWUrZgAWKOFtVRl2RKVdAyMYNM17WNzTC0cXPIsPbIBWX39NINoGRm5wnn5NJJi6AA505McANl7lCrpCuwtYhLKHOkHpkZgu31wAXQBuXFwQAAcKcBgsAPgkFHQ6bEIIEABXEWAGxGQ0KB8V2wAbVABzVDA4OkIfhIUBAIHeFG2AM0-hAIkoSCgqBEdGEEG27wQAE8AJJ_VAAD1sQII-IAgvjyBAoYFMdsGvRgEhvrDMW0FI8EOcmGxOK0-I0wrzIo1mkL6CsaiRMeTKdTSFBafTzAh3tdUPRJQQ0CJyKgqThNEcaXSQgAjBAiNkKGBgBDBeh6ZIwFQiOBIiBWhTQBDAADWIQ6Ek9pF-oDdcutMHxIXqwYUmIDGVUGsjPk0xNIRvlirNFrjNrt9MdyhgkgtUA9US1yD9ieS-dDIHDRE0CmjDFjVdICYYgagFRT1ozCnNIgAsuQwAAJVDkL4ACyg6iiw5bkYVJoYo_ztuCDFJOgAas7Xe7897awx7A2wGGGlm2zGqOquwQe_R7CpBwo0z-og-yBzLc8y7Xd6QPY8yxECtzxrf0rwsG87wja123oTtW27EJ3Cyb9SFXAhRwnadZwXJdrBMfCSAlHwNk2fRrlvPYwEUNEMRxPF8QACm2C07QgABKNcYFASBYA5bFEUoA5jiedBsF4kR-IAOgkzj1hIMQoFuFiGAAHmEcwAD4YGLCQ6CgisYFYBgYAAalkhBJNQShsHoPtJHFezbJdN0RAgazbIciSpLcvsvxWbz6D0gB6QyjPoezMIUaL4pgCCLPLAKbMS4KTmc1yPwmLyHMS0hfPdQLcscgq3M_Er9Li8hjI1HwgA) something to give you an idea:

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    time: '01-2023',
    directC: 10,
    directO: 10,
    directDiff: 0,
    advC: 10,
    advO: 7,
    advDiff: 3
  },
  {
    time: '02-2023',
    directC: 14,
    directO: 12,
    directDiff: 2,
    advC: 12,
    advO: 7,
    advDiff: 5
  },
  {
    time: '03-2023',
    directC: 8,
    directO: 6,
    directDiff: 2,
    advC: 14,
    advO: 6,
    advDiff: 8
  }
];

option = {
  dataset: [{source: dataset}],
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {
    formatter: displayIndex,
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['01-2023', '02-2023', '03-2023']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name:'Direct Orders',
      stack: 'direct',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'directO'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'Direct Carts',
      stack: 'direct',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'directDiff'
      },
      barMinHeight: 10,
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'ADV Orders',
      stack: 'adv',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'advO'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'ADV Carts',
      stack: 'adv',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'advDiff'
      },
      barMinHeight: 10,
    }
  ]
};


function displayIndex(params) {
  const dataItem = dataset[params.dataIndex];
  return  '<div> Direct: Carts - ' + dataItem['directC'] + ' Orders - ' + dataItem['directO'] + '</div>' +
          '<div> ADV: Carts - ' + dataItem['advC'] + '    Orders - ' + dataItem['advO'] + '</div>'
}
```

Second [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygiBTWBeGBtAUDGAb3wJigEsBbVALhgHIAGARgFoAmR9gZnoBoSBOOQBOqYFADCdZowGl4o8VADyMuYMViJAEXIAzfXQ0KEcAG7SYs-aTPm1MAOy2C9vYbrcSAX1vEFCmo6JnYOLl5XLWUrZgAWKOFtVRl2RKVdAyMYNM17WNzTC0cXPIsPbIBWX39NINoGRm5wnn5NJJi6AA505McANl7lCrpCuwtYhLKHOkHpkZgu31wAXQBuXFwQAAcKcBgsAPgkFHQ6bEIIEABXEWAGxGQ0KB8V2wAbVABzVDA4OkIfhIUBAIHeFG2AM0-hAIkoSCgqBEdGEEG27wQAE8AJJ_VAAD1sQII-IAgvjyBAoYFMdsGvRgEhvrDMW0FI8EOcmGxOK0-I0wrzIo1mkL6CsaiRMeTKdTSFBafTzAh3tdUPRJQQ0CJyKgqThNEcaXSQgAjBAiNkKGBgBDBeh6ZJWhTQBDAADWIQ6EmdpF-oDgDSN1vxIXqvoUmK9GVUGutMB8mmJpGDBAVJoY5stUQI5H-DEdygjMFdHujTpzMH9IEDcvjoYY4crBCjDG9UAqcetyYU5ERlAAygrPgDQO9YSEvmJWfydm6-63GAA6OI90hZgCy5DAAAlUOQvgALKDqKJr1NkRVmi3F23BBiknQANWLpc9DHsxertaImgUDfoJs_1IVt6HsFQuwURMoKiC903pLNizzEJHxfSs3xCT9K2_INgJJMMqHVZsYFA9wskg0g11zfsh0xEciDHCcGCnVAZxgOdgAXYwVyomBN23PcD2PU8kxICUfA2TZ9GuMAJHIfZUXRLFcUDfEAAptgtO0IAASl_AhQEgWAOWxfsDmOJ50GwTSRG0pcTLxfF1hIMQoFuMACHoAAeYRzAAPhgQsJDoSQLSgCAYFYBgYAAagshBTNQShsHodtJHFWLopUERAxECKovoTKTP7FL2wglZMu8gB6Xy_MKmK8NIbzapgVCQrC_Lori4qkpS_IMriwrSGy3LOvq-LEuSsDigGhgvJq8h_I1RNcEoTFJEPMKl3ANT6E-H4_jQT4JGATawB-OB-BgaTZL2DyNK0yhdP0mBDOgEskV1CAABlKUwHBnIIGERBgNTtS-9j9BgNaNq2n5VF2eSwDUnSl3BvU9ODAxQZsuy71QGAAEIMCwdGICXPNMeAsnfugJdtmuCBDzBz6MY2KDlgIGHNpEKA0fQFREZ2y5Wf1Gm_r8IgxCU-4NyRH4uTJ8UfB0jYVbWIA):

```js
const dataset = [
  {
    time: '01-2023',
    directC: 10,
    directO: 10,
    directDiff: 0,
    advC: 10,
    advO: 7,
    advDiff: 3
  },
  {
    time: '02-2023',
    directC: 14,
    directO: 12,
    directDiff: 2,
    advC: 12,
    advO: 7,
    advDiff: 5
  },
  {
    time: '03-2023',
    directC: 8,
    directO: 6,
    directDiff: 2,
    advC: 14,
    advO: 6,
    advDiff: 8
  }
];

option = {
  dataset: [{source: dataset}],
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {
    formatter: displayIndex,
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['01-2023', '02-2023', '03-2023']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name:'Direct',
      stack: 'direct',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'directO'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      id: 'Direct',
      stack: 'direct',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'directDiff'
      },
      itemStyle: {color: 'grey', opacity: 0.4},
      barMinHeight: 10,
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      name: 'ADV',
      stack: 'adv',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'advO'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'bar',
      id: 'ADV',
      stack: 'adv',
      encode: {
        x: 'time',
        y: 'advDiff'
      },
      itemStyle: {color: 'grey', opacity: 0.4},
      barMinHeight: 10,
    }
  ]
};


function displayIndex(params) {
  const dataItem = dataset[params.dataIndex];
  return  '<div> Direct: Carts - ' + dataItem['directC'] + ' Orders - ' + dataItem['directO'] + '</div>' +
          '<div> ADV: Carts - ' + dataItem['advC'] + '    Orders - ' + dataItem['advO'] + '</div>'
}

myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function (params) {
  const seriesList = [];
  for (series of myChart.getOption().series) {
    if (params.name !== series.id) {
      seriesList.push(series);
    }
  }
  myChart.setOption({series: seriesList}, {replaceMerge: ['series']});
});
```

Comment: I edited original post, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think this can be achieved in the same way I outlined with some modifications. You just need to exclude the carts from the legend by not specifying a name, change there color and transparency; for the legend you can listen to the 'legendselectchanged' event and remove / add the corresponding cart. I added another (incomplete) example to showcase how it can be done.